# Specify own colors on each bars respectively in Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, data-visualization, bokeh

I've a data frame in **pandas** having **x**, **count** and **colors** columns.

```
x   count   colors
1   4      #99d594
1   4      #99d594
2   3      #ffffbf
```

I want to plot a bar chart having **x** on x-axis and **count** on y-axis and **colors** column define color for **x** column respectively.

```
plt = Bar(df, label='count', title="Bar chart", legend='top_left', color="colors")
```

But **Bokeh** doesn't uses the given color codes in **colors** column. It uses their own itself but *#99d594 and #ffffbf are different in colors.* .

Given in below image. [image: pre-defined colors]

**Pseudo Code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {"x": [1,1,2],
 "count": [4,4,5],
 "colors": ["#99d594", "#99d594", "#ffffbf"] } )

plt = Bar(df, label='count', title="Bar chart",
          plot_width=700, plot_height=300, legend='top_left', color="colors")

output_file("test.html")
```

Answer (score 3):

Change for:

```
palette=[ "#99d594", "#ffffbf"]

plt = Bar(df, label='count', title="Bar chart",
      plot_width=700, plot_height=300, legend='top_left', 
      color=color( columns='colors', palette=palette, sort=False))
output_file("test.html")
```

Should do what you expect :)

Comment: `palette attribute` of `color method` that uses `palette variable` in sequence order. So, it draws first two bars as same color and third bar in another color. The solution is that `palette variable` values should be unique and in sequence order. i.e. `palette=["#99d594", "#ffffbf"]`. Please edit your answer to make it as correct